# In Log4j2, how to append same class logs of different priority levels in different files?

Tags: java, log4j2

These are my appender files-

```
    <Appenders>
        <File name="FirstLogToFile" fileName="logs/first.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%r %d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </File>
        <File name="SecondLogToFile" fileName="logs/second.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%r %d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
```

And these are my logger files-

```
        <Logger name="com.company.gaurav.Log" level="Fatal" additivity="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="FirstLogToFile"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="com.company.gaurav.Log" level="trace" additivity="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="SecondLogToFile"/>
        </Logger>
```

I can't append to FirstLogToFile, only SecondLogToFile.
The other workaround is to create a Root parent logger without any individual child logger, and that works. Can anyone please explain why this is not working.

Comment: Please take a look at [another answer I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53029597/3284624) and see if this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have two Loggers with the same name. D.B.'s answer is correct although a bit complicated for your question. I would only use the RoutingAppender if you need dynamic flexibility. If you know your appenders ahead of time it is preferable to configure them.

Also, you can put filters at various levels. D.B.'s linked answer filters at the appender, which is appropriate if you want specific output regardless of the logger. The way you worded your question though I would add the LevelRangeFilter to the Appender reference like this

```
<Logger name="com.company.gaurav.Log" level="trace" additivity="true">
   <AppenderRef ref="FirstLogToFile">
     <LevelRangeFilter minLevel="FATAL" maxLevel="FATAL" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
   </AppenderRef>
   <AppenderRef ref="SecondLogToFile"/>
</Logger>
```

I should also point out that I am not sure this will do what you really want. With this configuration the FirstLogToFile appender will get only fatal error messages while SecondLogToFile will get all log events. But that configuration seems to match what you showed in your example.